# php segmentation fault on a raspberry

Tags: php, linux, raspberry-pi3

I am trying to install "composer" (https://getcomposer.org/download/) for Mediawiki on a raspberry Pi 3.

To install that, I need to use the command line 
`php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"`

My problem : I get the error `Segmentation fault`.

Even trying `php` in the terminal returns `Segmentation fault`.

- My system is up to date.
- For other projects, the following packages are already installed and up to date on my raspberry : `nginx, php5, php5-fpm, mysql-server, php5-mysql`
- Restarting the system doesn't help.
- Stopping nginx service doesn't help.
- The commands `php5` also returns `Segmentation fault`.
- One more thing : trying the command line : php5-fpm returns :

`ERROR: An another FPM instance seems to already listen on /var/run/php5-fpm.sock
ERROR: FPM initialization failed`

Do you have any solution ?
Thank you in advance !!

Comment: Is the error really `Segmentation error` ? Is it [Segmentation fault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault) instead ?

Comment: Well ok, I am french, and the error displayed is : "Erreur de segmentation". I have edited my post.

Comment: Up !! No one have an idea?